# jScrollPane and Facebook Comments

Tags: javascript, facebook, jscrollpane

I'm building a site and I want to show facebook comments and use Jscrollpane but it's not working. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, this is supposed to be easy 'cause I don't want any fancy effect, just replace the ugly native scrollbar. That's it.

The comments show up but there's no scrollbar at all.

Thank all you in advance for your help.

```
   <div id="fb-root">/div>  

   <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

//This is the div for facebook comments

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="" data-num-posts="3" data-width="390" data-colorscheme="dark" style="height: 400px; overflow:auto;"></div>
```

//Script for JScrollpane

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function(){
                        $('.fb-comments').jScrollPane({
                            showArrows: true,
                            maintainPosition: false
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### For this, you need to set the `autoReinitialise` to `true`!

```
$('.fb-comments').jScrollPane({
    showArrows: true,
    maintainPosition: false,
    autoReinitialise: true
});
```

#### Explanation:

> Whether `jScrollPane` should automatically reinitialise itself periodically after you have initially initialised it. This can help with instances when the size of the content of the scrollpane (or the surrounding element) changes. However, it does involve an overhead of running a javascript function on a timer so it is recommended only to activate where necessary.